# Insertion sort and taking related arrays with it

Tags: vb.net

I need a bit of help with this insertion sort, The code I have so far is this:

```
Private Sub SortedList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim currentitem As Integer = 2
    While currentitem <= numitems
        currentdataitem = frmEntry.starname(currentitem)
        comparison = 1
        finish = False
        While comparison < currentitem And finish = False
            If currentdataitem < frmEntry.starname(comparison) Then
                shuffleitem = currentitem
                While shuffleitem > comparison
                    frmEntry.starname(shuffleitem) = frmEntry.starname(shuffleitem - 1)
                    shuffleitem = shuffleitem - 1
                End While
                frmEntry.starname(comparison) = currentdataitem
                finish = True
            End If
            comparison = comparison + 1
        End While
        currentitem = currentitem + 1
    End While
    arrayindex = 0
    For Me.arrayindex = 1 To numitems
        lstsorted.Items.Clear()
        lstsorted.Items.Add(frmEntry.starname(arrayindex))
        lstsorted.Items.Add(frmEntry.DOB(arrayindex))
        lstsorted.Items.Add(frmEntry.rank(arrayindex))
    Next
End Sub
```

This insertion sorts their names, but I also need to take their DOB and their rank with it, at what point in my visual basic code do I put this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the corresponding elements of DOB and Rank whenever you move the elements of starname.

Comment: I did that but it does not work, it makes allot of them the same but the last one is different. This is the new code, could someone please assist by explaining / showing me where it goes?

                    While shuffleitem > comparison
                        frmEntry.starname(shuffleitem) = frmEntry.starname(shuffleitem - 1)
                        frmEntry.DOB(shuffleitem) = frmEntry.DOB(shuffleitem - 1)
                        frmEntry.rank(shuffleitem) = frmEntry.rank(shuffleitem - 1)
                        shuffleitem = shuffleitem - 1
                    End While

can't format